# Transform a string of characters into a function

Tags: r, string, function, character

Is there another way  to transform a string of characters into a function other than the following?

Example: `x+2`

```
f <- function(x) {
     eval( parse(text=("x+2")) )
}

print( f(2) )
```

> 4

I do not find an alternative way.

Thanks you

Comment: If you provide more context it's possible people could come up with some solutions that would fit. E.g., why doesn't this suit your needs?

Comment: I have problems in shiny. I am transforming a text into a function: f <- function(x){eval(parse ( text=( input$text )))  },but when I execute the code it takes time to do the calculations. If instead of transforming the "text into function", I write the function directly, then I have no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about creating the function by pasting your string in as the body, then evaluating the whole thing?

```
str <- "x+2"
f <- eval(parse(text=paste("function(x) {",str,"}")))
f(2)
## 4
```

? That way the evaluation cost is paid once, up front, rather than every time the function is called ...

Another possibility is to create a function of x with an empty body, then fill in the parsed expression as the body ...

```
f <- function(x) {}
body(f) <- parse(text="x+2")
f(2)
```

By the way, I [hope you're being careful about what strings you evaluate](https://xkcd.com/327/), e.g. what happens if `str` is something like `"system('rm -rf /')"` ... ?

Answer (score 1):

I might have totally missed your point, but here's what I've got for you:

```
f1 <- function(x="x") {
  a <- as.expression(paste0(x,"+2"))
  print(class(a))
  return( eval(parse(text=a)) )
}
f1(2)
```

> 4